# How i can do this in scss

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, design-patterns, sass

How can I write this code in Sass?
I'm trying to target one same tag in different classes

```css
.vimcash__navbar-links_container p, 
.vimcash__navbar-sign p,
.vimcash__navbar-menu_container p {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: var(--font-family);
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-transform: capitalize;

    margin: 0 1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I been trying to something like this:

```css
.enterprise__navbar-links_container{
& .enterprise__navbar-menu-container {
        p {
        color: #333333;
        font-family: var(--font-family);
        font-weight: 500;
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 23px;
        text-transform: capitalize;

        margin: 0 1rem;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what's the problem with the first example?

Comment: no problem in the first example i just want to know if there is a different way to write this css in scss because it didn't work the way i do in the second example in scss and it didn't work the way i wrote it. in css neither

Comment: you can do the way you do it in the first one and just nest the p tag within, like this: ```.vimcash__navbar-links_container, .vimcash__navbar-sign, .vimcash__navbar-menu_container { p { } }```

Answer (score 1):

You can write it using the [parent selector](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector) and nesting like this:

```
.vimcash__navbar {
    &-links_container, &-menu_container, &-sign {
        p {
            color: #fff;
            font-family: var(--font-family);
            font-weight: 500;
            font-size: 18px;
            line-height: 25px;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            margin: 0 1rem;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }
}
```